# How can you send html and other files from a node.js server

Tags: node.js

I am running (and learning) a basic node.js program that returns unformatted numeric data in the response object. The chrome browser just shows that data unformatted on screen. However, now I want to return HTML files, so I read an HTML file using the fs module and it returned that in the response object. The browser is showing the entire html instead of interpreting it. Here's what I want to do:

1. Send an HTML file with a javascript code in it.
2. Connect the javascript on the client with that in the server to excahange more HTML, css, javascript, json or other objects like image files etc.

How can I establish this architecture? I am completely new to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set the content-type header properly.
2) Use frameworks like expressjs socket.io, etc